# If P!=NP, does there exist infinite hierarchy of languages between P & NP?

Tags: complexity-theory

This looks to me as some tweaking or generalization of Ladner's result on NP-I languages, can some help me in the right direction? or redirect me to some sources where this generalization is explicitly proven?

Comment: Doesn’t the original Ladner’s theorem already say exactly this? I’ve always seen it formulated this way.

Comment: Can you please share the proof link(the one you found easiest to understand)? I am really struggling with Ladner's theorem :( @EmilJeřábek

Comment: The proof of Ladner's theorem in "Computational Complexity" by Arora and Barak is pretty readable. I recommend you start there, as it would give you also the relevant background.

Comment: I haven’t checked the details, but I think the proof in Arora and Barak actually proves the more general Theorem 1 from Ladner’s paper (see my answer), if you read it with an arbitrary language $B$ in place of SAT.

Answer (score 3):

$\def\P{\mathbf P}\def\NP{\mathbf{NP}}$This already follows from Ladner’s original paper

> Richard E. Ladner: *On the Structure of Polynomial Time Reducibility*, Journal of the ACM 22 (1975), no. 1, pp. 155–171, doi [10.1145/321864.321877](https://doi.org/10.1145/321864.321877).

Theorem 1 in Ladner’s paper states:

> If $B$ is computable and not in $\P$ then there exists a computable $A$ such that $A\notin\P$, $A\le^\P_mB$, and $B\nleq^\P_TA$.

Assuming $\P\ne\NP$, you can apply it to $B=L_0=\mathrm{SAT}$ to obtain $L_1=A\notin\P$ such that $L_1\lneq^\P_mL_0$, i.e., $L_1\in\NP$ and $L_1$ is not $\NP$-complete. But you can now iterate this process: taking $L_1$ as the new $B$, you obtain $L_2\notin\P$ such that $L_2\lneq^\P_mL_1$, etc., obtaining an infinite sequence of $\NP$-languages strictly decreasing w.r.t. poly-time reducibility:
$$\mathrm{SAT}=L_0\gneq^\P_mL_1\gneq^\P_mL_2\gneq^\P_mL_3\gneq^\P_mL_4\gneq^\P_m\dots$$

Comment: How much about the poset $(\mathsf{NP},\le_m^\mathsf{P})$ is known assuming $\mathsf{P}\not=\mathsf{NP}$ in general? E.g. is it consistent that it's dense?

Comment: @NoahSchweber I would think so, but I am not really familiar with this line of research. There are some more result in Ladner’s paper: if $\mathbf{P\ne NP}$, there are incomparable NP languages.

Comment: @NoahSchweber At the very least, I believe Ladner’s argument relativizes, which implies that $(\mathrm{NP},\le_T^P)$ is densely ordered (if $\mathrm{P\ne NP}$). I’m not sure about $\le_m^P$.